# Is it bad practice to commit placeholder/design text into source control?

Tags: svn, testing, view

Is it bad practice to have placeholder data in your source control repository? For example, when building a view is it ok to commit something like this:

```
...
<span id="username">LoremIpsum</span>
<span id="karma">999</span>
...
```

...or should I put the variable names in during design, and only view the work-in-progress view via some sort of test:

```
...
<span id="username"><?php echo $username; ?></span>
<span id="karma"><?php echo $karma; ?></span>
...
```

```
...
//test file kept in a repository/tests directory
$username = "LoremIpsum";
$karma = 999;
$page = new Page($username, $karma);
$page=>render();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the placeholder data in test directories/files completely seperate from the code. [You will not remember to take the placeholders out before production.](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/We-Burned-the-Poop.aspx)